# Is there a NATIVE ANDROID button for NEXT or CONTINUE? If so, what does it look like?

Tags: android

Does Android use or have native buttons for something like NEXT or CONTINUE - I'm working on a 2 step process and want to use what Android has NATIVELY vs Custom design.

For example, IOS has the native TOP NAVIGATION that you can change.

[image]

In this instance, we are using a CONTINUE button up top. This is a native option with IOS. Does Android have anything like this? If so, what does it look like and where is it placed. I cannot find anything on this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No android do not have native button.

Answer (score 1):

No android do not have native button. 
You have to make your custom xml for action bar and add next/continue buttons.

A good way to learn about what action bar/ App bar provides and what it doesn't visit [Material.io](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#anatomy).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a [floating action button (FAB)](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button).

I think this is as close as it gets for a native next button, although it can be used for many things.

For android design components I would recommend you having a look at [Material.io](https://material.io/). There you will get in depth explanations for almost all android design patterns!